# Neo4j direction between nodes

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, directions

Suppose I have A class which HAS A class B. Then in the graph the direction is outgoing from A or incoming to A? My main question is how to figure out direction between nodes based on class relationships in a OOD. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily traverse both ways in Neo4j.  My usual default here is outgoing, that said... it depends on your model.

As an exercise, think about people and houses.  Does a person have a house or a house have occupants Try thinking about relationship names here.  Do they OWN the house, LIVE AT the house or what?

```
Person--{has}-->house
Person--{livesat}-->house
Person--{owns}-->house
House--{has}-->occupant
```

They're all slightly different relationships.  Apply this thinking to your own model and go for what you think's best.  I'm not a fan of "by" relationships, e.g house--{ownedby}-->person as they're simply traversing an "own" relationship backwards and are better expressed that way around.